# RecyclerView Doesn't Reload Code When Reopening Item

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, initialization, android-recyclerview

When I first start up my app and the user clicks on an item in a recyclerview, everything initializes as expected.

[image: Correct Initialization]

When the user hits the back button to go back to the main item list page and then clicks on the same or another item, the page is not loaded the same.

[image: Incorrect Initialization]

My initial layout is the same as the second image without the location name and coordinates updated.

[image]

What frustrates me is the day names are initialized in the same exact method. I have debugged it in many ways and have found that the code must not be run - the code inside of it has NO affect on the outcome of the item's detail page when it is reloaded. This code only affects the actual layout the FIRST time it is run and has no affect any other time.

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
    public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final List<LocationContent.LocationItem> mValues;

        public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<LocationContent.LocationItem> items) {
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
            holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final View mView;
            public final TextView mIdView;
            public final TextView mContentView;
            public LocationContent.LocationItem mItem;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code that is supposed to be run:**

```
Log.i("LOAD DATA", "Called");
        Log.e("SWITCH CASE (IDF)", AssetLoader.getMondayName(mItem.id));
        // To layout below the textView to avoid crashes
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textView);
        switch(AssetLoader.getLastItemDayName(mItem.id)) {
            case "Sun":
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Mon":
                monday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Tues":
                tuesday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Wed":
                wednesday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Thurs":
                thursday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Fri":
                friday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "Sat":
                saturday.setLayoutParams(p);
                // Make sunday layout before monday (as its default is below textView)
                p.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.monday);
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
            case "":
                sunday.setLayoutParams(p);
                break;
        }

        Log.e("MONDAY NAME EDIT()", AssetLoader.getMondayName(mItem.id));
        if (!AssetLoader.dataInMonday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getMondayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getMondayName(mItem.id).equals("Monday:")*/) {
            monday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            monday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsMonday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            monday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            monday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            monday.setText(AssetLoader.getMondayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsMonday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                monday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                monday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsMonday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInTuesday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getTuesdayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getTuesdayName(mItem.id).equals("Tuesday:")*/) {
            tuesday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tuesday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsTuesday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            tuesday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tuesday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tuesday.setText(AssetLoader.getTuesdayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsMonday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                tuesday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                tuesday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsTuesday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInWednesday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getWednesdayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getWednesdayName(mItem.id).equals("Wednesday:")*/) {
            wednesday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            wednesday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsWednesday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            wednesday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            wednesday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            wednesday.setText(AssetLoader.getWednesdayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsWednesday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                wednesday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                wednesday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsWednesday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInThursday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getThursdayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getThursdayName(mItem.id).equals("Thursday:")*/) {
            thursday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thursday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsThursday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            thursday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            thursday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            thursday.setText(AssetLoader.getThursdayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsThursday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                thursday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                thursday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsThursday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInFriday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getFridayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getFridayName(mItem.id).equals("Friday:")*/) {
            friday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            friday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsFriday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            friday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            friday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            friday.setText(AssetLoader.getFridayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsFriday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                friday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                friday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsFriday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInSaturday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getSaturdayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getSaturdayName(mItem.id).equals("Saturday:")*/) {
            saturday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            saturday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsSaturday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            saturday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saturday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saturday.setText(AssetLoader.getSaturdayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsSaturday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                saturday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                saturday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsSaturday(mItem.id));
            }
        }

        if (!AssetLoader.dataInSunday(mItem.id)/*AssetLoader.getSundayName(mItem.id).equals("") || AssetLoader.getSundayName(mItem.id).equals("Sunday:")*/) {
            sunday.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sunday_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AssetLoader.setItemDetailsSunday(mItem.id, "");
        } else {
            sunday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sunday_detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sunday.setText(AssetLoader.getSundayName(mItem.id));
            if(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsSunday(mItem.id).equals("")) {
                sunday_detail.setText(R.string.no_data);
            } else {
                sunday_detail.setText(AssetLoader.getItemDetailsSunday(mItem.id));
            }
        }
```

Please note that the Log.e and Log.i calls are not even being displayed in logcat/Android Monitor when the app is run. THE CODE IS BEING CALLED WHEN THE REST OF THE USER INTERFACE IS BEING CALLED! Thanks for any information you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the problem. When the DetailView for my Item was loading the first time, my variables for monday, tuesday, etc were null so they were set to the TextViews on the current layout. When the back button was pressed, these variables were no longer null but still pointed to the previous layout's variables.

**Incorrect Code:**

```
if(monday == null) {
    monday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.monday);
    tuesday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
    wednesday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
    thursday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thursday);
    friday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friday);
    saturday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saturday);
    sunday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sunday);
}
if(monday_detail == null) {
    monday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.monday_detail);
    tuesday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_detail);
    wednesday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_detail);
    thursday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_detail);
    friday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friday_detail);
    saturday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saturday_detail);
    sunday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sunday_detail);
}
```

**Correct Code (Without null checks):**

```
    monday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.monday);
    tuesday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);
    wednesday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
    thursday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thursday);
    friday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friday);
    saturday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saturday);
    sunday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sunday);
    monday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.monday_detail);
    tuesday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_detail);
    wednesday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_detail);
    thursday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_detail);
    friday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friday_detail);
    saturday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saturday_detail);
    sunday_detail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sunday_detail);
```

So by removing the null checks, my code is all initialized correctly every time and has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Set your adapter for RecyclerView inside onResume method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change the outcome of the layout loading. It still doesn't initialize properly when its reopened. The problem still persists